# Swift CoreData: sort by calculated upcoming birthday with NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my iOS 14/Swift 5 app I use CoreData to store A `Friend` entity to store a Friends name and birthday. `upcoming birthday` returns the upcoming Birthday calculated from the Friends birthday.

```
extension Friend {

    @NSManaged public var birthday: Date
    @NSManaged public var familyName: String?
    @NSManaged public var givenName: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: String?

    public var upcomingBirthday: Date {
        nextBirthday(forBirthday: birthday)
    }
}
```

I tried to use "upcomingBirthday" in an `NSSortDescriptor` like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "upcomingBirthday", ascending: true)
```

But I get the error "keypath 'upcomingBirthday' not found in entity"

Is there any way to sort by upcomingBirthday even though it is not a direct CoreDate attribute or would I have to fetch all Friends and sort after fetching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use custom properties as key (paths) in sort descriptors of Core Data entities.

Declare `upcoming` in an extension of `NSDate` (not Swift `Date`) as property (no parameter) and then use the key path `birthday.upcoming`

Comment: Does this work? I get the same error "reason: 'keypath birthday.updacoming not found in entity Friend", why? I have another Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66730049/coredata-nssortdescriptor-by-computed-value-with-2-keypaths, any suggestion?